# How to change default configuration of cluster

Tags: arangodb

Running following configuration, three servers cluster:
Version:

> full-version-string: ArangoDB 3.11.0 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, build tags/v3.11.0-0-gd91ddf405d3, VPack 0.2.1, RocksDB 7.2.0, ICU 64.2, V8 7.9.317, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023

Agnecy

```
arangod --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8531 \
  --agency.my-address tcp://X.X.X.111:8531 \
  --server.authentication false \
  --agency.activate true \
  --agency.size 3 \
  --agency.supervision true \
  --database.directory /arangodb/agency/agent111

arangod --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8531 \
  --agency.my-address tcp://X.X.X.222:8531 \
  --server.authentication false \
  --agency.activate true \
  --agency.size 3 \
  --agency.supervision true \
  --database.directory /arangodb/agency/agent222

arangod --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8531 \
  --agency.my-address tcp://X.X.X.333:8531 \
  --server.authentication false \
  --agency.activate true \
  --agency.size 3 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.111:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.222:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.333:8531 \
  --agency.supervision true \
  --database.directory /arangodb/agency/agent333
```

Databases:

```
arangod --server.authentication=false \
  --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8530 \
  --cluster.my-address tcp://X.X.X.111:8530 \
  --cluster.my-role DBSERVER \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.111:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.222:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.333:8531 \
  --database.directory /arangodb/database/dbserver333 &

arangod --server.authentication=false \
  --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8530 \
  --cluster.my-address tcp://X.X.X.222:8530 \
  --cluster.my-role DBSERVER \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.111:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.222:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.333:8531 \
  --database.directory /arangodb/database/dbserver222 &

arangod --server.authentication=false \
  --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8530 \
  --cluster.my-address tcp://X.X.X.333:8530 \
  --cluster.my-role DBSERVER \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.111:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.222:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.333:8531 \
  --database.directory /arangodb/database/dbserver333 &
```

Coordintators

```
arangod --server.authentication=false \
  --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8555 \
  --cluster.my-address tcp://X.X.X.111:8555 \
  --cluster.my-role COORDINATOR \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.111:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.222:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.333:8531 \
  --database.directory /arangodb/coordinators/coordinator111 &

arangod --server.authentication=false \
  --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8555 \
  --cluster.my-address tcp://X.X.X.222:8555 \
  --cluster.my-role COORDINATOR \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.111:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.222:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.333:8531 \
  --database.directory /arangodb/coordinators/coordinator222 &

arangod --server.authentication=false \
  --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8555 \
  --cluster.my-address tcp://X.X.X.333:8555 \
  --cluster.my-role COORDINATOR \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.111:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.222:8531 \
  --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.333:8531 \
  --database.directory /arangodb/coordinators/coordinator333 &
```

Instead of above for example for the coordinatior on X.X.X.333:8555 it running following:

```
arangod --configuration none \
        --server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529 \
        --server.authentication true \
        --javascript.startup-directory /arangodb/server/usr/share/arangodb3/js \
        --javascript.app-path /tmp/arangodb-app.egel \
        --server.authentication=false \
        --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8555 \
        --cluster.my-address tcp://X.X.X.333:8555 \
        --cluster.my-role COORDINATOR \
        --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.111:8531 \
        --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.222:8531 \
        --agency.endpoint tcp://X.X.X.333:8531 \
        --database.directory /arangodb/coordinators/coordinator333
```

As result I can't connect to the coordinator since I am trying to connect remoutely and coordinator listening on 127.0.0.1

How I can ensure it not trying to pick up any default configuration and running exactly what I am asking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've pasted it is not clear what problem you've encountered and what you want to achieve. Do you have trouble with configuring network connectivity?

Is there a reason why you trying to run it with plain `arangod` executable instead of using official ["ArangoDB Starter"](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/cluster/deployment/using-the-arangodb-starter/) application?

It is specifically designed to setup an ArangoDB cluster. It also tracks server status and restarts them automatically in case of failure.

Full reference:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangodb-starter/

Comment: Thanks,
The problem that coordinator seems to be hardcoded to run on 127.0.0.1 and listen on the 127.0.0.1 and, therefore you can't connect to coordinator remotely.
Nothing to do with starter.
As well, even using starter it would not change, try.

Regards